# Is it possible to prevent a user from setting a property on the command line?

Tags: c#, properties, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

In an msi package produced by wix, how can I prevent a user from overriding a property via the command line?

I know properties can be scoped by marking them `PUBLIC` or `private`. However when I use a private property for a launchcondition, my installer fails in the `ExecuteSequennce`.

```
<Condition Message="!(loc.LCMsg)">private = "true" OR Installed</Condition>
```

I am setting the property in a custom action that is scheduled to run in the UISequence. I would like this property to be private, so the user can't just assign the value `true` on the commandline and therefore skip the check this condition should actually implement.

I have now resorted to using a  public property and am using a type51 CA to set its value to false before calling my own CA. If a user was to set the value on the command line, it would get overriden by the type51 CA:

```
    <CustomAction Id="Type51Init" Property="PUBLIC" Value="false" />
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="Type51Init" Before="MyCA">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallUISequence>
```

This seems rather hacky though, and I'd really like to know if there is another way to prevent the user from setting the property via the command line.

Comment: Not really, no. However, if the UI sequence is suppressed with a silent install, where does the value come from? Do you have a CA in the execute sequence?

Comment: Not yet, no. At the moment, if the UI Sequence is suppressed, the vaule won't be set. Should I simply copy the CA and run it in the execute sequence, too? (It is not altering the target system in any way.)

Comment: You could run it in the execute sequence if it's not been run in the UI sequence, yes, with the caveat that I don't know what it does. In many cases, properties are set on the command line in a silent install, that was why I asked, but for this property I assume that will never be an option.